# Show Yahoo in short-form signup

Tags: feature-request, login, yahoo

When giving feedback (if I am not logged in), an overlay shows up:

[image: Thanks for the feedback! Google, Facebook, Stack Exchange]

The login screen shows a different lineup:

[image: Log In Stack Exchange, Google, Facebook, Yahoo!]

Why is Yahoo shown on one view but not the other?

Comment: My guess is design choice, they had room only for three and I guess those are the most popular.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd that's not completely obvious -- based on the heights, they should have only included 2.